# Postgres function return unknown number of columns

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql

I've been looking for a way to create a function which will take json as an input in which I will specify columns and table name and give me those columns as an output.

Let's say I have the following table:

```
 col1 | col2  | col3  
------+-------+-------
    1 | 303.8 | 331.9
    5 | 373.2 | 765.8
    1 | 467.4 | 427.5
    5 | 139.5 | 500.5
    4 | 350.6 | 706.2
```

I would like to call a function this way:

```
SELECT foo('{"dimensions":["col2", "col3"], "table":"test"}');
```

which will give:

```
 col2  | col3  
-------+-------
 303.8 | 331.9
 373.2 | 765.8
 467.4 | 427.5
 139.5 | 500.5
 350.6 | 706.2
```

The problem is I am not sure what my output should be as it cannot be "table" because I do not know columns and their types before executing the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo ( j json ) RETURNS ??? AS
$$

DECLARE
   dimensions json ARRAY;
   sql_string TEXT;
   field TEXT;
   table_name TEXT;

BEGIN
   dimensions := ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements(j->'dimensions'));
   table_name := TEXT ( j->> 'table' );

   sql_string := 'SELECT';

   FOREACH field IN ARRAY dimensions LOOP
      sql_string:= sql_string || ' ' || field || ',';
   END LOOP;
   SELECT TRIM (trailing ',' from sql_string) INTO sql_string;

   sql_string := sql_string || ' FROM ' || table_name ;

   EXECUTE sql_string INTO ???;
   RETURN ???;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think that can be done. Your best bet is to return something in a defined type which can be parsed by whatever would use this function into rows/fields.

Answer (score 0):

In short, refcursor & dynamic query.

---

Make your function `RETURNS refcursor`.

In `DECLARE` section:

```
_str text;
_cur refcursor = 'name_of_refcursor_1';
```

In code:

```
_str = 'SELECT ';
FOR _column IN <array or select to make column list>
LOOP
  _str = _str || _column.name || ', '
END LOOP;
_str = TRIM(TRAILING ', ' FROM _str);
_str = _str || ' FROM my_table1';

OPEN _cur FOR
EXECUTE _str;

RETURN _cur;
```

Outside from function:

```
FETCH ALL FROM "name_of_refcursor_1";
```

or

```
FOR _row IN FETCH ALL FROM "name_of_refcursor_1"
...
```